# Regex to filter string and get results as a list

Tags: c#, regex

I have strings in the following format :

```
\r\nab-CD:2\r\nab-EF:1\r\nbc-DE:3\r\ndz-LF:1\r\nkr-TZ:2\r\nef-DD:1\r\nlv-ER:2\r\ndf-QW:3\r
```

I have to filter out the `xx-XX` values which have value `1`. (`xx-XX:1`)

So in the example string, the values I have to get as result are

```
ab-EF
dz-LF
ef-DD
```

Which Regex would give me the result as a list?

Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Regex.Matches` with the following regex

```
[a-z]{2}-[A-Z]{2}(?=:1)
```

Code:

```
var list = Regex.Matches(input, @"[a-z]{2}-[A-Z]{2}(?=:1)")
                .Cast<Match>()
      .         .Select(match => match.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: @vks it's not. I answered first and it had `:` first and then changed it to `-`, which you' could have clearly pointed out, instead of answering and commenting that my answer is a duplicate. Check the timestamps if needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
[a-z]{2}-[A-Z]{2}(?=:1)
```

Try this See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/fA6wE2/15

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [a-z]{2}                 any character of: 'a' to 'z' (2 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -                        '-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   [A-Z]{2}                 any character of: 'A' to 'Z' (2 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    :1                       ':1'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```